# MPI kill worker while keeping the master running

Tags: c++, mpi, openmpi

My question is simple, I'm using OpenMPI to parallelize my code and I want to keep the master running and kill the other workers. After they finished part of the code they're not needed anymore and the master can finish the rest.

I looked everywhere for an implementation, all I can find is the argument for `srun` `--kill-on-bad-exit` but I can't find an equivalent one for `mpirun`. But I would prefer to find a way to do this directly in the c++ code.

Comment: Do you run the `master` on a login node? or on a compute node? If the latter, is it running in the same job with the workers?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I run the master on a compute node, the master also does similar work than the workers. But after the first calculations only one node is needed to do the rest.

Comment: So from a SLURM point of view, you will want to "shrink" the job once the master becomes alone working, right? did you solve that problem first?

Comment: Exactly, I don't want to keep charging cpu hours for the other workers, I thought "--kill-on-bad-exit" will do that on slurm, but I haven't tried it yet, I thought I will ask here first if there is a proper implementation.

Comment: I do not think `--kill-on-bad-exit` can help here. Anyway, if your job allocation is remains the same, you will be charged for all the nodes, regardless they are idle or running some workers.

Comment: Ahh I didn't know, thanks for clearing this up. Is it even possible then to de-allocate some workers in srun? Or maybe I should just separate my code to two different runs?